# PLESK direct www.domain.com to another server with a un

Tags: domain, ip

I got a customer where I host mail and www address on my server with PLESK 9.2

I want to direct the www address to another IP address like this:

```
Original:
www.domain.com -> IP: 1.2.3.4
mail.domain.com -> IP: 1.2.3.4
webmail.domain.com -> IP: 1.2.3.4

New:
www.domain.com -> IP: 22.22.22.22
mail.domain.com -> IP: 1.2.3.4
webmail.domain.com -> IP: 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a DNS configuration issue.  Do you also host their DNS?  If yes there will be a DNS section on your Plesk dashboard that will allow you to point www to a new IP address, if not, you need to find their DNS provider and make the change there.